# Why does moving the UV map not affect the image on my object?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm following this to tutorial to add images to my objects: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eiDrRa6JvQ0

But I have a problem, when I move the image mapping, it doesn't change the actual location from the object.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Your UV map probably isn't connected. Make sure *Texture Coordinate node > UV* is plugged into Vector input of the image texture.

Comment: The problem here is not the connection of the UV map and I'm not sure how familiar @titosg is with the node editor (yet). He was following the above linked Youtube beginner tutorial and there the node editor is not used at all so I provided an answer that doesn't need the node editor. As you can see in the material setup on the right of the screenshot, he is clearly using an Environment Texture with vector set to default - the problem is, the Environment Texture doesn't use UVs as default, but the Image Texture does. And this accidental mistake might happen to him in the node editor, too.

Answer (score 0):

My Spanish is not the best, but since you have the "Equirectangular" option chosen for the projection which is not possible if you used Image Texture ("Imagen") for the color like it's shown in the tutorial, I guess you might have accidentally chosen Environment Texture ("Imagen de entorno"), which is suitable for the world background. So, simply choose "Imagen" in the color selection and open your picture.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete Jachym answer, this is the shader node configuration:

[image]